# When you read entity relationships, do you read the cardinalities from one side of the entity, or from each entity in the relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, erd

I'm going to use the classic "Instructor and Courses" example. In this scenario, an Instructor Entity can teach multiple courses, but a course can have one teacher. I am aware this is a one-to-many relationship, but I have a question about actually reading the digram. The diagram will be linked accordingly in the text below.

Would the one-to-many be read in this fashion? 
[image: 1]

So, from the Instructor Entity **to** the Course entity?

Or, is the relationship read like this?

[image: 2]

As in, from the minimum and maximum cardinality signs?

**Edit:** [Here is a good example of why I’m confused](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/crow-s-foot-notation)

Notice how the relationships are introduced as the second way I described, i.e. in my second screenshot:

[image: 2]

You read it from one side. However, at the bottom of that blog post, you see how those relationships are abstracted differently? Take that one-to-many example at the bottom. In that one-to-many, there also exists a one-to-one relationship from the course to the lecturer. So why is it, then, that this is abstracted into a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Hi. What is your textbook/reference? What does it say? There are different conventions. They include look-across & look-here. The wiki article on ERDs is not too bad about that. Also the kind of diagram you give is wrongly called an ER diagram by methods & presentations that don't understand the ERM. Also this is a faq.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Here: Include with credit any text elsewhere necessary to your question. And give text capturing the diagram layouts.